# Oracle SQL*Plus: How to include current schema in prompt?

Tags: oracle, schema, sqlplus, prompt

In SQL*Plus, I can set the prompt to include the instance name:

```
SET SQLPROMPT "_USER'@'_CONNECT_IDENTIFIER > "
```

I can also query for the current schema:

```
select sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_schema' ) from dual;
```

Is there a way to get the current schema into the prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
undefine schema_display
col schema_display new_value schema_display

set termout off
select lower(sys_context('userenv', 'current_schema')) schema_display from dual
/
set termout on

set sqlprompt "&&schema_display.':'_USER'@'_CONNECT_IDENTIFIER > "
```

So:

```
USER@SID > alter session set current_schema="TEST";

Session altered.

USER@SID > -- run the above
TEST:USER@SID >
```

However, the prompt stays set to that value until another SET SQLPROMPT is performed. You need to put the code to switch schemas and create the schema_display variable in a script (like "switch_schema.sql"):

```
alter session set current_schema="&new_schema"; 

undefine schema_display 
col schema_display new_value schema_display 

set termout off 
select lower(sys_context('userenv', 'current_schema')) schema_display from dual; 
set termout on 

set sqlprompt "&&schema_display.':'_USER'@'_CONNECT_IDENTIFIER > "
```

The &new_schema variable causes SQL*PLUS to prompt you for the schema you want to switch to.

```
USER@SID > @switch_schema 
Enter value for new_schema: TEST 
old   1: alter session set current_schema="&new_schema" 
new   1: alter session set current_schema="TEST" 

Session altered. 

test:USER@SID >
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott! Works as advertised. The only thing I changed: I omitted the double quotes around the variable in `alter session set current_schema="&new_schema"` because that makes the comparison case-sensitive. Thanks again!